# Пропал примонтированный раздел Suse11.3

Tags: монтирование, suse, раздел

Ни с того, ни с чего, пропал примонтированный раздел флешки, теперь вставляя флешку - пишет, что невозможно смонтировать и естественно с ней нет возможности работать! Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте примонтировать вручную:

```
su // получаете права rootfdisk -l
```

Находите свою флешку например /dev/sdb, монтируете командой

```
mount /dev/sdb /media/
```

Флешка должна примонтироваться в раздел media, если этого не произходит попробуйте отформатировать флешку